# theharvester cant use wfuzz

Tags: python, libcurl, pycurl, kali-linux

I've started to work with theharvester in Kali Linux. But I've a problem... when the program starts, give me an error.
[theharvester error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEdx6.png)

At this moment, I visit wfuzz documentation and i do that they say:

```
$ pip install wfuzz

$ git clone git://github.com/xmendez/wfuzz.git

$ python setup.py install
```

And I restart the program: ... The same error.
Now, i check that I've the dependencies libcurl (DONE), in adition is the lastest version.
But the problem still there.
I find in the documentation guide for install pycurl aganist ssl (my problem):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev
mkdir ~/python-pycurl-openssl
cd ~/python-pycurl-openssl
sudo apt-get source python-pycurl
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pycurl
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo dpkg-source -x pycurl_7.19.0-3build1.dsc
cd pycurl-7.19.0
edit debian/control file and replace all instances of “libcurl4-gnutls-dev” with “libcurl4-openssl-dev”
sudo PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
sudo dpkg -i ../python-pycurl_7.19.0-3build1_i386.deb
```

But surprise: another problem. 
After do `cd ~/python-pycurl-openssl` I try the next comand `sudo apt-get source python-pycurl`

[Installation problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQl0i.png)

And i can`t continue with it.
After search by google for hours, I decide try if wfuzz.py works (go to the problem roots), and occurs this:
[wfuzz problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ2aO.png)

try to install fuzzing package `pip install fuzzing`... But same problem

Anyone who knows what happend? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To fully troubleshoot this you may need to use a different os.

- Ubuntu
- Debian

`virtualenv -p python3 theharvester`
Then clone the harvester and test it from the virtual env in either Ubuntu or Debian.

**Plan B**

Install wfuzz for python3

`pip3 install wfuzz`

According to https://wfuzz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ Wfuzz supports Python 3. **The use of Python 3 is preferred (and faster) over Python 2**.

I have [theHarvester](https://www.nmmapper.com/kalitools/theharvester/email-harvester-tool/online/) But not eccounter that error before.